# Does JavaFX have something like Swing's TransferHandler?

Tags: javafx-2

What I'm trying to achieve is to "secretly" edit some html code before I paste it into an HTMLEditor. Can anyone think of a way of doing something like this in JavaFX 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally what you can do is add a `ChangeListener` to a property which is changing (for example a `TextArea`'s `TextProperty`) inspect the new value in the change listener and modify it to something you want.  This strategy is not exactly the same as a `TransferHandler`, but (I think) would work in some places where you would have used a `TransferHandler` in Swing.  Unfortunately, in the case of a `HtmlEditor`, you would not be able to use such a strategy because `HtmlEditor` text is not implemented as a listenable property (although there is a request to make it a property in a future JavaFX release: [RT-18436](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-18436)).

Looking at the [JavaFX drag and drop documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm), JavaFX does support a [TransferMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/input/TransferMode.html) which can be queried on reception of a drag event to perform different actions (such as copying, linking or moving data).

Also, if you look at example 6 from the drag and drop documentation, you can see that it is possible to set an [onDragDropped](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onDragDroppedProperty) event handler for a node which can intercept the `DragEvent` and take appropriate action at that time (such as setting the `htmlText` of the `HtmlEditor` to a modified version of the dragged data).  If you have difficulty overriding the default `onDragDropped` function of the `HtmlEditor`, then you could place an [event filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#addEventFilter%28javafx.event.EventType,%20javafx.event.EventHandler%29) on the `HtmlEditor` which allows you to catch, handle and consume the relevant drag event as you wish.